# How to solve the Logistic equation with a sinusoidal oscillating growth rate

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}N}{\mathrm{d}t}=(\cos(\alpha t)+1)\cdot rN(c-N) - \mu N.
$$
Any hints as to what type of differential equation this is or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: The equation is first order and separable, thus explicitly solvable. See also the eerily similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134853/showing-that-a-periodic-solution-exists-using-a-sinusoidal-logistic-equation .

Comment: @FritsVeerman Eerily similar, but the parenthesis are different, so this one isn't separable. Although the question you linked is from the same OP, so maybe they made a typo here?

Comment: Yeah, I made two posts - one where the whole equation is affected by the oscillation and this one where only the regeneration rate (r) is affected by the oscillation. I was able to solve the other equation easily (as it is separable) but I am not sure how to solve this one!

Answer (score 1):

@Dylan is right: the equation, in this form, is not separable. However, if you introduce
$ n(t) = \frac{1}{N(t)}$, then you obtain for $n(t)$
$$
\frac{\text{d} n}{\text{d} t} = \mu n- r(\cos(\alpha t) + 1)(c n - 1),
$$
which is a linear first order ODE. Hence, you can solve this equation explicitly using variation of constants. Hope this helps!